# Does an open vote counter a close vote?

Tags: support, closing-questions

Does voting to "leave open" counter a "close" vote?

From what I've seen, it doesn't seem to.

How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I THINK* your leave open vote will count towards removing the item from the queue, but will not undo a close vote.

- 5 votes to close
- 3 reviews to get out of the queue
- 3 reopen votes opens the question again.

I don't think skips have any effect but to let the person go on to the next question.  As a mod, I skip all the time because my votes are binding.  I'll cast the last or next to last close vote, but I hesitate to cast the first.

Also, close votes get stale and expire.  So if you vote to close and there isn't a consensus, eventually the question gets back to 0 close votes.

Comment: Thanks MrChrister!  Lame implementation since it has the same effect as "skip".  Oh well.

Comment: @quantycuenta No, skip leaves the item in the queue for others to review and potentially close.  Don't forget that 5 to close, 3 to reopen is also a balance in the close system.

Comment: How many "don't close"es required to take it out of the queue?

Comment: @quantycuenta - here is the SO people discussing the feature.  I think it is pretty up to date: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/24229